# How to Fix this error While Opening Image

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This is the **OpenImage code** :

```
private void openWebView(String docPath) {

            if (docPath.toLowerCase().endsWith("png") ||
                    docPath.toLowerCase().endsWith("jpg") ||
                    docPath.toLowerCase().endsWith("jpeg")) {

                urlWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imgBelow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //            Glide.with(CalanderAssignmentDetailActivity.this).load(docPath)
    //                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
    //                    .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    //                    .crossFade()
    //                    .into(imgBelow);
                images = new ArrayList<>();
                images.add(new CustomImage(docPath, "1"));

                overlayView = new ImageOverlayView(CalanderAssignmentDetailActivity.this);
                imagrBuliderDilog = new ImageViewer.Builder<>(CalanderAssignmentDetailActivity.this, images)
                        .setFormatter(getCustomFormatter())
                        .setStartPosition(0)
                        .setImageChangeListener(getImageChangeListener())
                        .setOverlayView(overlayView)
                        .show();
                overlayView.setImageDilogListner(imagrBuliderDilog);

            } else {
                imgBelow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                urlWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                urlWebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
                        + docPath);

            }
        }
```

Here is the **LOGCAT ERROR** :

> W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference

Comment: Check the parameter you are passing while calling `openWebView` method. The parameter you are passing is null, hence `.toLowerCase()` is throwing a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

are you sure docPath is not empty or null?

try this:

```
if(docPath !=null && !docPath.isEmpty()){
   //your code
}
```